# How can I disable customized tabitem "close button" for some specific tabs

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have the following XAML code for a tabitem with a close button. How can I access ("***cmdTabItemCloseButton***" --> Close Button on tabitem). Actually I want to disable this button for some specific tabs using c# code not from XAML.

This is my code:

```
<Style x:Key="CustomTabItem" TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
                <!-- The Grid helps defining the general height of TabItems. -->
                <Grid Height="18" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" MinWidth="70">
                    <Border Name="Border"
                     Background="#FF1E1E1E"  
                     BorderThickness="0,0,1,0">
                        <Border.BorderBrush>
                            <SolidColorBrush Color="#FFC7C7C7"/>
                        </Border.BorderBrush>
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="17"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentSite"
                                     VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                     HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                     ContentSource="Header"                                             
                                     RecognizesAccessKey="True"/>                            
                            <Button x:Name="cmdTabItemCloseButton" ToolTip="Close"
                           Style="{StaticResource TabItemCloseButtonStyle}"
                           Command="{Binding Path=Content.DataContext.CloseCommand}"
                           CommandParameter="{Binding  
                               RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, 
                               AncestorType={x:Type TabItem}}}"
                           Grid.Column="1"
                           Margin="0,0,0,0" Click="cmdTabItemCloseButton_Click"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                </Grid>
```

Comment: Please improve your question with what you did to try to access to that value

Comment: For example I have 5 TabItem. I want to disable the "close button" (cmdTabItemCloseButton) for tab 1,3,5. I want to get access of "cmdTabItemCloseButton" via code so that I can use cmdTabItemCloseButton.IsEnabled to disable or enable the close button.  
Actually,  need to know how I can get access of this variable from code. I am too new on C#. :-)

Comment: Do you use `TabItem` class to create your tabs or you have a custom class e.g. `MyTabItem` that is derived from `TabItem`?

Comment: Thank you.

Actually I do not have any class as such like MyTabItem. I directly call like below.

<TabItem Style="{StaticResource CustomTabItem}" x:Name="hMainTabScript" Header="Script Explorer" TabIndex="0" ToolTip="Script Explorer" MouseEnter="hPropertyTabLeft_MouseEnter" MouseLeave="hTab_MouseLeave">

Is it possible to get the variable without a class declaration.

Answer (score 1):

**First approach**

You can find a button within a template and enable/disable it in the following way:

```
var b = (Button)tab.Template.FindName("cmdTabItemCloseButton", tab);
b.IsEnabled = ...
```

`tab` is an instance of `TabItem`. However, it will only work if you tab has been already loaded i.e. `TabItem.IsLoaded` is `true`. If you want to be sure thta a control has been loaded you can subscribed `Loaded` event.

**Second approach**

Here is another approach, that according to me is more elegant. It uses a custom `MyTabItem` class.

*MyTabItem class*

This a basic implementation. I suggest to read this [article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) about `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

```
namespace MyNamespace
{
    public class MyTabItem : TabItem, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }

        private bool _isButtonEnabled;

        public bool IsButtonEnabled
        {
            get { return _isButtonEnabled; }

            set
            {
                if (value != _isButtonEnabled)
                {
                    _isButtonEnabled = value;
                    NotifyPropertyChanged();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

*How to use MyTabItem in XAML*

```
<Window xmlns:myNamespace="clr-namespace:MyNamespace" ... >
    ...
    <TabControl>
        <myNamespace:MyTabItem x:Name="tab1" Style="{StaticResource CustomTabItem}"></myNamespace:MyTabItem>
        <myNamespace:MyTabItem x:Name="tab2" Style="{StaticResource CustomTabItem}"></myNamespace:MyTabItem>
    </TabControl>
</Window>
```

*How to modify CustomTabItem style*

```
<Button 
    x:Name="cmdTabItemCloseButton"
    IsEnabled = "{Binding IsButtonEnabled,     
    RelativeSource=
            {RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type TabItem}}}"
...
/>
```

*How to enable/disable a button*

```
tab1.IsButtonEnabled = false;
```